# Getting "unrecognized selector sent to instance" in code for ios8

Tags: objective-c, json, ios8

This code work in ios7, but I am now getting the error :
-[__NSCFString objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

.m file

```
//get the JSON response
NSDictionary *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization
                          JSONObjectWithData:urlData
                          options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                          error:&error];
//Parses the "success" value
success = [jsonData[@"success"] integerValue];

//Was it successful?
if(success){
    //successful, save the profile gathered into global gMyProfile
    NSArray *profileJSON=jsonData[@"myProfile"];
    for (NSDictionary* dict in profileJSON)
    {
        NSLog(@"First_Name: %@", dict [@"first_name"]);
    ...
```

The error is happening on the NSLog statement and from a little research it is complaining about the dict[@"first_name"]);

login.py

```
....
#Query for user
db_cursor = db.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
db_query = """SELECT users.email, users.first_name, users.profile_pic_path, \
              FROM users,data WHERE users.email='%s' \
              AND users.user_id=data.user_id""" % user_email
db_cursor.execute(db_query)

#If there is one record containing the username check password
if(db_cursor.rowcount == 1):
    user_profile = db_cursor.fetchone()
...
    json_obj= {'success': 1, 'myProfile': user_profile,} 
...
```

JSON Output:

```
{'myProfile': {'first_name': 'Matt', 'email': 'matt@email.com', 'profile_pic_path': 'default'}, 'success': 1}
```

All this code was working, I have not changed anything. 
Any help will be greatly appreciated!!!!

Comment: Without seeing the JSON we can't do much.

Comment: editted the post with the JSON output :)

Comment: Go to json.org and study the JSON syntax.  It only takes 5-10 minutes to learn.  Then come back here and explain how hosed up your code is.

Answer (score 0):

`dict` is not a dictionary.  It is a string.   Print it and you'll know which string it is.

More likely than not, your JSON is not what you think it is.   In particular, the `myProfile` value is a string instead of a dictionary.

What happens if fetchone() returns None;  do you end up with a string in your JSON?

Comment: I am just perplexed on why this worked fine in ios7. It parsed and saved the data perfectly. Ill study up on it :)

Comment: @lr100 - It is possible that the other end sends an array when there are multiple data sets and an object when there is only one.  This is not common, but not unheard of.  If this is the case you need to test what you receive to determine if "myProfile" is an array or a dictionary.

Comment: What @HotLicks said; you should take apart the received JSON and validate the structure of the data.  Even in production, you might want to harden your code against unexpected types in the JSON data.

Comment: I am very new to this and would love a link about hardening JSON if you have time to provide one. :)

Comment: @lr100  There isn't much to it.  If you pull a value from your JSON, make sure it is non-nil/NULL and use `isKindOfClass:` to ensure that it is of the expected type.

Answer (score 0):

Changed in the .m

```
//Was it successful?
if(success){
   //successful, save the profile gathered into global gMyProfile
   NSArray *profileJSON=jsonData[@"myProfile"];
   for (NSDictionary* dict in profileJSON)
   {
   ...
```

to

```
//Was it successful?
if(success){
    //successful, save the profile gathered into global gMyProfile
    NSDictionary* dict=jsonData[@"myProfile"];
    //no more for loop
    ...
```

The python JSON module returns a single dictionary instead of an array of a single dictionary when there is one element. If there are multiple it returns an array of dictionaries.

Still don't know why this didn't give me trouble in ios7 but did in ios8.